# StateProvider resolve gives Unknown Provider error

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, dependency-injection, routes, angular-ui-router

I am trying to use the resolve parameter in $stateProvider but its not working out for me.  I have the following state:

[image]

Next step would be inject it into the controller:

[image]

And then time to use it

[image]

Doesn't work:

[image]

Also note that the console.log is actually printing the correct return value of the promise and the function is running correctly.  However, the error somehow messes up the data and things look weird.

The problem seems to be my injection of 'moments' into my controller.  As soon as I take that dependency out of my controller it doesn't complain about that anymore.  Of course, it gives me a different error, "Moment is undefined".

Am I missing a step here?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure that MomentController isn't used anywhere else. Try to move `resolve` from `views` to state object and see what happens. Consider providing a fiddle/plunk that can replicate the issue.

Comment: *Note: We do not recommend using resolve of AngularUI Router. The recommended approach is to execute any logic needed before beginning the state transition.* [-- Ionic Framework  ionNavView Directive API Reference](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/)

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that, thanks.  How exactly do I "execute any logic needed before beginning the state transition" without resolve?